# creating multiple input box by using for loop and accessing them store their values in database

Tags: php

how to create an array of input box which has name in iterative order like name=name1,name2 ..... like  and i want access them on next page  by using PHP

```
    echo"<form action='addprogrammerdetails.php' action='post'>";
                echo"<table border='0' class='corner' width='600'>";
                echo"<tr>";
                echo"<td>";
                echo"&nbsp;";
                echo"</td>";
                echo"</tr>";
                echo"<tr>";
                echo"<td colspan='2' bgcolor='#E57614'>";
                echo"PROGRAMMER DETAILS";
                echo"</td>";
                echo"</tr>";

                session_start();
                $nprog=$_SESSION['nprog'];
                for($i=1;$i<=$nprog;$i++)
                {
                    echo"<tr>";
                    echo"<td>";
                    echo"<table>";
                    echo"<tr>";
                echo"<td width='300'>";
                echo"Programmer Number:";
                echo"</td>";
                echo"<td>";

                echo"<input type='text' name='no[]' value='$i' disabled/>";
                echo"</td>";
                echo"</tr>";
echo"</table>";

                echo"</td>";

                echo"</tr>";

                }
                echo"<tr>";
                echo"<td colspan='2' align='center'>";
                echo"<input type='submit' value='SUBMIT'/>";
                echo"</td>";
                echo"</tr>";
                echo"</table>";
                echo"</form>";
                ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you name your element with `[]`, you can access it as an array in PHP

```
$no1 = $_POST['no'][0];
$no2 = $_POST['no'][1];
$no3 = $_POST['no'][2];
```

OR

```
foreach($_POST['no'] as $values) {
  // do something with $value
}
```